# Regular Express for Javascript - Contain a specific word in the beginning after get any character until a certain character comes

Tags: javascript, python, regex, regular-language

I need a certain type of regular expression where I need list of special type of strings from a string. Example input:

```
str = 'this is extra data which i do not need /type/123456/weqweqweqweqw/ these are more extra data which i dont need /'
```

Result needed:

```
/type/123456/weqweqweqweqw/
```

Here the `/type/` string will be constant and the remaining will be dynamic i.e. `123456/weqweqweqweqw` and the last string will be `/`.

I tried:

```
var myRe = /\/type\/(.*)\//g
```

But this matches everything from `/type/` to the end of the string.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all at writing such a regular expression yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: var myRe = /\/type\/(.*)\//g;

Comment: I tried this it is returning till the end '/'

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating `.`, which will match anything, repeat anything but a space via `\S+`, so that only the URL part of the string will be matched:

```js
const str = 'this is extra data which i do not need /type/123456/weqweqweqweqw/ these are more extra data which i dont need /';
console.log(str.match(/\/type\S+/));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tagged Python, so here is a solution:

```
import re

re.search(r"/type/[^/]*/[^/]*/",str)
Out: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(39, 66), match='/type/123456/weqweqweqweqw/'>
```